# A converted tflite file is not work in flutter

Tags: flutter, tensorflow-lite

I converted h5 file to tflite.
This h5 file was a ml5 Json model.
I Just converted to h5 file by myself. 
But it's not work with error code.

ml5 model link : https://github.com/CodingTrain/website/tree/master/learning/ml5/7.2_pose_classifier/p5-multi/1%20-%20Data%20Collection/model2

Windows10, Python 3.6.8, tfv2.0.0

code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
model=tf.keras.models.load_model("E:\h5\outputs\model.h5")
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("E:\h5\converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

I converted file with these code

and This model file is put into my app.

Error code:

```
[+14766 ms] D/ViewRootImpl@454dd0a[MainActivity]( 1610): ViewPostIme pointer 0
[ +133 ms] D/ViewRootImpl@454dd0a[MainActivity]( 1610): ViewPostIme pointer 1
[  +13 ms] I/tflite  ( 1610): Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
[  +36 ms] I/flutter ( 1610): success
[  +12 ms] I/CameraManagerGlobal( 1610): Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state now
CAMERA_STATE_OPEN for client com.example.examplerealtime API Level 2
[   +9 ms] D/SensorManager( 1610): registerListener :: 1, LSM6DSO Acceleration Sensor,
200000, 0,
[  +86 ms] W/Gralloc3( 1610): allocator 3.x is not supported
[ +573 ms] I/CameraManagerGlobal( 1610): Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state now
CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client com.example.examplerealtime API Level 2
[  +37 ms] I/CameraManagerGlobal( 1610): Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state now
CAMERA_STATE_IDLE for client com.example.examplerealtime API Level 2
[ +146 ms] I/Choreographer( 1610): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too
much work on its main thread.
[ +499 ms] I/CameraManagerGlobal( 1610): Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state now
CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client com.example.examplerealtime API Level 2
[ +118 ms] D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation( 1610): IRenderScriptDevice::getService()
[  +11 ms] D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation( 1610): IRenderScriptDevice::getService()
returned 0x78d5593060
[        ] D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation( 1610): HIDL successfully loaded.
[   +1 ms] V/RenderScript( 1610): ARM mali (64 bit) RenderScript Compute Driver
[  +40 ms] V/RenderScript( 1610): Successfully loaded runtime: libRSDriverArm.so
[   +1 ms] D/        ( 1610): Successfully queried cache dir:
/data/user_de/0/com.example.examplerealtime/code_cache
[        ] D/RenderScript( 1610): Setting cache dir:
/data/user_de/0/com.example.examplerealtime/code_cache
[  +31 ms] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610): Failed to handle method call
[        ] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported
value: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=3
[        ] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610):       at
io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:278)
[        ] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610):       at
io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMethodCodec.encodeErrorEnvelope(StandardMethodCodec.java
:69)
[        ] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610):       at
io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.error(MethodChannel.ja
va:236)
[        ] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610):       at
sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.onMethodCall(TflitePlugin.java:113)
[        ] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610):       at
io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.
java:226)
[        ] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610):       at
io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:8
5)
[        ] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610):       at
io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:631)
[        ] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610):       at
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
[        ] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610):       at
android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
[        ] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:197
)
[        ] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610):       at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7777)
[        ] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
Method)
[        ] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610):       at
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
[        ] E/MethodChannel#tflite( 1610):       at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
[   +4 ms] E/flutter ( 1610): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled
Exception: PlatformException(error, Unsupported value:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=3, null)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
(package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #3      Tflite.runModelOnFrame
(package:tflite/tflite.dart:67:27)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #4      _CameraState.initState.<anonymous
closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_realtime_detection/camera.dart:49:22)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #5      CameraController.startImageStream.<anonymous
closure> (package:camera/camera.dart:353:20)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #6      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #7      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #8      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded
(dart:async/zone.dart:987:7)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData
(dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #10     _DelayedData.perform
(dart:async/stream_impl.dart:594:14)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #11     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext
(dart:async/stream_impl.dart:710:11)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #12     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure>
(dart:async/stream_impl.dart:670:7)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #13     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1180:38)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #15     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter ( 1610): #16     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure>
(dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #17     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #18     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #19     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #20     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure>
(dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #21     _microtaskLoop
(dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): #22     _startMicrotaskLoop
(dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 1610): 
[ +482 ms] W/System  ( 1610): A resource failed to call close. 
[   +1 ms] W/System  ( 1610): A resource failed to call destroy. 
[  +18 ms] I/chatty  ( 1610): uid=10403(com.example.examplerealtime) FinalizerDaemon
identical 1 line
[        ] W/System  ( 1610): A resource failed to call destroy. 
[+7729 ms] I/CameraManagerGlobal( 1610): Camera 0 facing CAMERA_FACING_BACK state now
CAMERA_STATE_CLOSED for client com.example.examplerealtime API Level 2
```

What is the cause of the error?